# Play audio file using AVAudioPlayer swift

Tags: swift, audio, swift2, avaudioplayer

I am downloading the audio message first then play it using Avaudioplayer

```
downloadTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(urlStr, completionHandler: { (URL, response, error) -> Void in

           self.play(URL!)


})
downloadTask
```

This works fine, but if I call play(URL) method after saving the response URL that I have stored in NSUserDefaults. The URL is same in both cases. I have checked it. its something like:

> file:///Users/mymac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/X-CD91-XXXXXXX-XXX-XXXXXX/data/Containers/Data/Application/XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_InUTA3.tmp

Passing this file url to:

```
func play(url : NSURL) {

        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()

        } catch let error as NSError {
            //self.player = nil
            print(error.localizedDescription)

        } catch {

            print("AVAudioPlayer init failed")
        }

    }
```

Url path is same, but the audioPlayer is unable to play the sound, it shows the following error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

Can anyone guide me in this regard?

Thanks.

Comment: So...just to understand you correct. If you call `play` with a URL that you have stored in your UserDefaults...it works? And if you call it straight here in the completion handler of `downloadTaskWithURL ` it does not work...correct? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: You need to store it with proper file extension. .tmp can never be played, If you know whats the type of the file, rename it to that proper name. And then play it.

Comment: @pbodsk nop the URL with UserDefaults doesnt work correct it works correct when i call Play() in the completion block it works right after the download.

Comment: Ah, OK, Thanks :) Before you exit the `completionHandler` you must move the file somewhere else. As it says here about the `location`: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsession/1411608-downloadtaskwithurl "The location of a temporary file where the server’s response is stored. You must move this file or open it for reading before your completion handler returns. Otherwise, the file is deleted, and the data is lost.", so if you don't do that already, then that could be why it works in the `completionHandler` and not later.

Comment: This also explains why you crash, you just pass it a force unwrapped `URL` and since there is no longer an item at that location which you've saved in your UserDefaults, it crashes

Comment: it means i cannot save .tmp file url in the UserDefaults? i need to save the file before completion block ends. But iOS cannot allow to save something in the local path or storage.

Comment: Yes you need to move the file to another URL before the completion block ends, and then you can save the URL of your new location to UserDefaults. Have a look at this blog post to see how to save in the document directory in iOS: http://sketchytech.blogspot.dk/2016/02/swift-download-file-using-nsurlsession.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen from the comments above the problem was that the downloaded file was not moved before completing the `completionHandler` of the `downloadTask` method.

As it says in the [description](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsession/1411608-downloadtaskwithurl) of the `location` parameter

> The location of a temporary file where the server’s response is stored. You must move this file or open it for reading before your completion handler returns. Otherwise, the file is deleted, and the data is lost.

Therefore, in your `completionHandler` you must move the file to another location that you control before ending the `completionHandler`.

This probably also explains the crash. If the "temp" URL is saved to UserDefaults in the `completionHandler` then that URL is no longer valid when the `completionHandler` has completed. So when you then later call

```
play(URL!)
```

with a force unwrapped URL that is now invalid, you get a crash.

Therefore, as an extra safety measure, try unwrapping the URL before trying to use it:

```
if let url = urlFromUserDefaults {
    play(url)
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks it works. Now i have moved the file in the documents directory in the completion handler and accessed the path. Thank you

Comment: you're welcome, glad you got it working in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write this...

```
 do
        {
            self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:Url)
            self.player?.numberOfLoops = 0
            self.player?.prepareToPlay()
            self.player?.volume = 1.0
            self.player?.play()
            self.player?.delegate=self
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print(error)
        }
```